# Magento2.4 for cms page add layout

Tags: magento2, layout

Have custom layout updates generally available for all pages, categories and products, so users can select and update the layout without creating many files with the same code over and over.
It would save time if the user wants only to repeat an already made custom layout update.
[image]

```
cms_page_view_selectable_2021-11-23_empty.xml
cms_page_view_selectable_2021-11-24_empty.xml
cms_page_view_selectable_2021-11-25_empty.xml
```

If I have a lot of page layouts like this. You don't have to create a lot of XML files like this. Feels too unreasonable whether there is a method that only needs to create a file. You can use a lot of pages
How to do that，
Who can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: In this layout, I want to remove the header footer. How do I do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two files for custom layout

**1 - Create layouts.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

This file will registered custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom">
        <label translate="true">custom layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

After creating above file you can check your custom layout in admin panel.

**2 - Create custom.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom.xml

This file will manage design for your layout page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Now, flush the cache and check the new custom layout in admin panel configuration setting.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe the problem clearly.

Comment: Good question. One project I checked, for better or worse, was re-using the same custom layout update across ~800 categories. In order to migrate to the new system this would require 800 physical custom layout files, one for each category, which is a laughable prospect.

In addition to the ability to create custom layout update files that are specific to one product, category, or cms page, I think there also needs to be the ability to create globally available custom layout updates, that can be applied to any given entity.

Comment: my cmspage layout :cms_page_view_selectable_2021-11-22_empty.xml ；cms_page_view_selectable_2021-11-23_empty.xml ；cms_page_view_selectable_2021-11-24_empty.xml；Is there a common layout method

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26901
There are instructions here but I can't find the answer

Comment: Please follow this link https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-layout-dropdown-on-cms-page-after-magento-2-3-4/

Comment: I know the method you mentioned, and I want to know how to make a custom layout that can be used on many pages at the same time.

Comment: have you followed magecomp link?

Comment: Yes  I followed  magecomp  link

Comment: In this layout, I want to remove the header footer. How do I do that

Comment: ``<referenceContainer name="root">
        <referenceContainer name="head" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="notifications" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>`` Please add this code in your layout xml file

Comment: I can only set it to take effect in layout Update XML, but not in Layout

Comment: of course you can use in layout xml file too.. just please add code in <body></body> tag. after </head>